# how to check whether a connection is closed or not in java connection pooling

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

In the following program I kept execution in sleep mode. But still the con obj is not closed.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;
public class ConnPool {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users");
    p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    p.setUsername("root");
    p.setPassword("root1");
    p.setJmxEnabled(true);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(10000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(10000);
    p.setMaxActive(100);
    p.setInitialSize(10);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(10000);
    p.setMinIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"
            + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
    DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
    datasource.setPoolProperties(p);

    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = datasource.getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from emp");
        int cnt = 1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println( "Name:" + rs.getString(1)+ " Address:" + rs.getString(2) );
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        Thread.sleep(40000);
        System.out.print(con.isClosed());
    } finally {
       /* if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a connection pool, you still need to explicitly close the connection by calling [`Connection.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29). This will signal to the connection pool that the connection is free again and can be returned to the connection pool.

The `Connection` you get from the connection pool is not the actual physical connection to the database, but a logical connection that is a wrapper or proxy for the actual physical connection. For some tasks (most notable `close()`) it will implement slightly different behaviour (so that the connection pool can re-use it), but to the end-user it behaves as if it is a normal connection (eg all dependent objects should be closed).

You are not very explicit in your question, but I will assume that you meant to ask why the connection pool hasn't reclaimed the connection yet even though you set a timeout. I can think of several reasons:

1. You set the `removeAbandonedTimeout` to 60 seconds, while you sleep for only 40000 milliseconds (40 seconds),
2. The implementation might use a cooperative way of reclaiming 'abandoned' connections (for example it might only check when a new `Connection` is requested, or when the pool is getting low on available connections)